# Laravel and Fractal: Duplicates with belongsToMany relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Fractal in combination with Eloquent (Laravel) and I'm running into an issue with models that have a many-to-many (belongsToMany) relationship. I'm using the JsonApiSerializer and I just can't seem to find the proper place to remove duplicate entries from an included resource.

For instance, I have a many-to-many relationship between User and Email. When I pull down my list of emails from my API I am seeing duplicates in "users" (because the same user is attached to more than one email).

I added the following snippet which uses php `array_unique` but it seems to muck up the json output a bit (below). Is there a better spot to hook into and remove duplicates?

Duplicates:

```
return $this->manager->createData($resource)->toArray();
```

Unique:

```
    foreach($this->manager->createData($resource)->toArray() as $key => $resource)
    {
        $resources[$key] = array_unique($resource, SORT_REGULAR);
    }

    return $resources;
```

However, when using `array_unique` the output changes from:

```
users: [
    {
        id: "53e8ea180454040b008b4569",
        ...
    },
    {
        id: "53e8ea180454040b008b4568",
        ...
    }
]
```

to

```
users: {
    0: {
        id: "53e8ea180454040b008b4569",
        ...
    },
    1: {
        id: "53e8ea180454040b008b4568",
        ...
    },
}
```

Comment: So in the result you get, the user is nested in the email resource?

Comment: Should've mentioned that the "user" resource is sideloaded with the "email" resource.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that your output have to be an `array []` but you getting an `object {}` - use `array_values()` on the `return` statement.

In your code:

`return $resources;`